# iOS Programming Convert Storyboard to NIB

Tags: ios, xcode, xib, uistoryboard, nib

I am making an iOS app (iPad) that has a very complex layout. I could try to use Auto Layout to accomodate orientation switching, but it's simply to complicated. I would like to have two seperate nib's, one for each orientation.

So here's the question: How do I convert an app using Storyboards to use Nibs/Xibs?

Comment: don't do this. Storyboards have big advantages for localization and probably other stuff, and a NIB can be expressed perfectly as a Storyboard. You could break your storyboard into multiple pieces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better solution might be to have also a copy of your landscape view in storyboards and then switch between the view controllers when rotation occurs to landscape etc.
You can register for rotation events.

Comment: I have done this and then made the landscape view controller a delegate of the portrait (so that all buttons etc. are controlled from the portrait controller) and have the landscape controller appear as modal view controller over the portrait one - this was important so that the portrait view controller would not get deallocated when the landscape view was presented.

Answer (score 3):

Don't do this unless you really think that you have to. I takes a very long time. With that said, I've been dumb enough to try this a few times, and you really have to edit a lot of code from being segues, to loading up the view controller along with it's `NIB` name, and then copy all of your designs for each respective view into it's respective `NIB`.

Good luck!